# What is the fastest correct way to detect that there are no duplicates in a JSON array?

Tags: json, algorithm, rust, serde

I need to check if all items are unique in an array of `serde_json::Value`. Since this type does not implement `Hash` I came up with the following solution:

```
use serde_json::{json, Value};
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn is_unique(items: &[Value]) -> bool {
    let mut seen = HashSet::with_capacity(items.len());
    for item in items.iter() {
        if !seen.insert(item.to_string()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    true
}

fn main() {
    let value1 = json!([1, 2]);
    assert!(is_unique(&value1.as_array().unwrap()));
    let value2 = json!([1, 1]);
    assert!(!is_unique(&value2.as_array().unwrap()));
}
```

I assume that it should only work if `serde_json` is built with `preserve_order` feature (to have objects serialized in the same order every time), but I am not 100% sure about it.

**Main usage context**:

JSON Schema validation. "[uniqueItems](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#uniqueness)" keyword implementation.

**Related usage case**

Deduplication of JSON arrays to optimize JSON Schema inference on them.

For example, the input data is `[1, 2, {"foo": "bar"}]`. A straightforward inference might output this:

```
{
    "type": "array", 
    "items": {
        "anyOf": [
            {"type": "integer"}, 
            {"type": "integer"},
            {"type": "object", "required": ["foo"]}
        ]
    }
}
```

values in `items/anyOf` can be reduced to only two values.

**Question**: What would be the most time-efficient and correct way to check that there are no duplicates in an arbitrary JSON array?

I used `serde_json = "1.0.48"`

**Rust**: 1.42.0

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=26491642caf1c3e8c31a8d7a60f31a5e)

Comment: Do you know anything about the types of the items in the slice?

Comment: Arbitrary values, i.e any `serde_json::Value` instances, the array is not sorted.

Comment: How do you define equality of mappings?

Comment: Key/value pairs are equal, keys are strings, values - any other `Value`. Empty mappings are equal.

Comment: So order does not matter? I think the fastest solution would be to implement a fast hash on a newtype wrapper for `Value`, so you can use `HashSet` directly on that wrapper without converting to strings. For mappings, you will need to implement an order-independent hash based on the hashes of the key/value pairs – see [Python's `frozenset` hash algorithm as an example](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/71a3522ef85df06a3acc718107360e37e4116a15/Objects/setobject.c#L757-L801).

Comment: Hashing can be implemented significantly faster than string conversion. You won't need any heap allocations to compute the hashes.

Comment: Yes, the order of keys in a mapping does not matter, e.g. `{"a": 1, "b": 2}` is equal to `{"b": 2, "a": 1}`

Comment: why json should change the general answer ?

Comment: It limits possible item types to ones defined by the JSON spec. I assume that generic answer might be not the fastest one for these specific types

Comment: why don't use use serde properly and convert to your type ? Value is not mean to be use like that

Comment: @Stargateur The OP specified that the entries in the array can each be an arbitrary JSON value. While this use case may appear a bit surprising, it seems at least conceivable to me.

Comment: How would you define proper usage? I'd give more context -  it is about JSON Schema validation ("uniqueItems" keyword), which doesn't imply any user-defined types

Comment: @Stranger6667 would you mind adding your last comment to the question? that's really helpful context.

Comment: @SvenMarnach . Added. Also, there is another usage for me. Optimizing schema inference for JSON arrays, to have fewer detected types. I'll add more examples to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting each array item to a string is rather expensive – it requires at least one string allocation per item, and quite likely more than that. It's also difficult to make sure mappings (or "objects" in JSON language) are represented in a canonical form.

A faster and more robust alternative is to implement `Hash` for `Value` yourself. You need to define a newtype wrapper, since you can't implement a foreign trait on a foreign type. Here's a simple example implementation:

```
use serde_json::Value;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};
use std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher;

#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct HashValue<'a>(pub &'a Value);

impl Eq for HashValue<'_> {}

impl Hash for HashValue<'_> {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        use Value::*;
        match self.0 {
            Null => state.write_u32(3_221_225_473), // chosen randomly
            Bool(ref b) => b.hash(state),
            Number(ref n) => {
                if let Some(x) = n.as_u64() {
                    x.hash(state);
                } else if let Some(x) = n.as_i64() {
                    x.hash(state);
                } else if let Some(x) = n.as_f64() {
                    // `f64` does not implement `Hash`. However, floats in JSON are guaranteed to be
                    // finite, so we can use the `Hash` implementation in the `ordered-float` crate.
                    ordered_float::NotNan::new(x).unwrap().hash(state);
                }
            }
            String(ref s) => s.hash(state),
            Array(ref v) => {
                for x in v {
                    HashValue(x).hash(state);
                }
            }
            Object(ref map) => {
                let mut hash = 0;
                for (k, v) in map {
                    // We have no way of building a new hasher of type `H`, so we
                    // hardcode using the default hasher of a hash map.
                    let mut item_hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
                    k.hash(&mut item_hasher);
                    HashValue(v).hash(&mut item_hasher);
                    hash ^= item_hasher.finish();
                }
                state.write_u64(hash);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The value for `None` is chosen randomly to make it unlikely to collide with other entries. To calculate hashes for floating point numbers, I used the `ordered-float` crate. For mappings, the code calculates a hash for each key/value pair and simply XORs these hashes together, which is order-independent. It's a bit unfortunate that we need to hardcode the hasher used for hashing the map entries. We could abstract that out by defining our own version of the `Hash` trait, and then derive concrete implementations of `std::hash::Hash` from our custom `Hash` trait, but this complicates the code quite a bit, so I wouldn't do that unless you need to.

We can't derive `Eq`, since `Value` does not implement `Eq`. However, I believe this is just an oversight, so I [filed an issue to add an `Eq` implementation](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/issues/638) (which the PR has been accepted for, so it will land in some future release).

Comment: How this is suppose to work if collection is heterogeneous ?

Comment: @Stargateur It operates on `Value`, which is an arbitrary JSON value.

Comment: yes but why a number couldn't collide with a string ?

Comment: @Stargateur Hashes can always collide. I don't understand what you are getting at.

Comment: Would `f64.to_bits()` work for the corresponding `Number` case? As far as I can see `ordered_float` also converts the value to `u64`. Are there any significant differences?

Comment: @Stranger6667 I wasn't really sure whether all finite floating-point numbers have a unique representation, in particular denormal numbers. After thinking about the representation a bit, I now believe that in IEEE-754-2008 they do, and that the more complex implementation in `ordered-float` only makes sure that an `f32` and an `f64` representing the same number hash to the same hash value. So I believe that using `x.to_bits().hash(state)` should be safe. No guarantees!

Comment: Thanks for this very informative post.

Answer (score -2):

Depends if JSON array is sorted or not. If it is sorted you can use binary search to check the value is matched with other values. To sort you can use merge sort. Total complexity will be O(nlogn + logn). Or you can iterate sequentially and check for duplicate rows O(n^2).

Comment: If the array is sorted, you don't use binary search – you simply iterate over the array and check whether any item equals the previous item. In a sorted array, duplicates are adjacent. However, this requires that the items can be sorted in the first place, and the question gives no indication that they can.